# Basic Auth Required with just extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

We have some public content on the cloud and I am trying to use Basic Auth to deter people from accessing our non-production web-site unless they are on our corporate network.

Everything is working until I submit a request that is just an extension such as '/.js'.

```
$ wget https://test.domain.com/.js
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.
```

If I add a file name, I am not asked for to authenticate. I get a 200 if the file actually exists.

```
$ wget https://test.domain.com/x.js
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-05-29 16:59:35 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Here is the Basic Auth configuration. It is the .htaccess directory in the document root.

```
SetEnvIf     HOST             "^www.domain.com$"    allowProduction
SetEnvIF     X-Forwarded-For  "123\.123\.123\.123"  allowEmployee

AuthType     Basic
AuthName     "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile /location/of/passwords/.htpasswd

Order        Deny,Allow
Deny         from all
Satisfy      any
Require      valid-user
Allow        from env=allowProduction
Allow        from env=allowEmployee
```

I modified the log format to display X-Forwarded-For since Apache sits behind a load balancer.

```
123.123.123.123 test.domain.com - - [29/May/2014:16:54:48 -0400] "GET /.js HTTP/1.0" 401 497 "-" "Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)"
123.123.123.123 test.domain.com - - [29/May/2014:16:59:35 -0400] "GET /x.js HTTP/1.0" 404 287 "-" "Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)"
```

I even tried adding some rule based on the request URI. I tried a few variations with and without the leading '/'. None of them worked.

```
SetEnvIf     Request_URI      "^/\..*$"             allowJunk
```

And then added the following.

```
Allow        from env=allowJunk
```

We do have a rewrite rule to forbid requests that have a leading '.' but that is a 403 and not a 401. A 403 is acceptable since the browser can ignore it. A 401 requires a user to enter the user name and password.

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
```

An example of a forbidden request.

```
$ wget https://test.domain.com/x/.js
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-05-29 17:04:18 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

The simple solution would be to not request any leading '.' URLs but we are using someone else's framework and we get these requests on some browser. Rewriting the framework for a small percentage of our customers is not desirable. Prompting them for a password is even less desirable.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Wes.

Comment: Your problem is the order in which authorization and rewriting are processed, I assume – your `RewriteRule` can’t “catch” the resources with a leading dot, authorization kicks in before already. (I bet if you enter valid auth credentials for such a resource, you get your 403 from rewriting _afterwards_?) As a quick fix, maybe try to put the `Require` directive into a `Files` directive, that targets only files that do not start with `.`

Comment: I was aware of the order because I tried using Rewrite to set the environment variables. Passing the user and password does result a 403. What I am still unclear about is why the `SetEnvIf` fails. Changing just the `.js` to a PHP page that just dumps `phpinfo()` shows I am matching both `SetEnvIf`. I do not have access to the httpd.conf so maybe I am missing something.